# Android application makes Touchwiz crash

Tags: android, samsung-touchwiz

I have i huge problem. When i install my application in usb debugging mode on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 with JELLY_BEAN android versions its crash Touchwiz and i cant do anything on my device. Its strange becouse on Genymotion virtual device its behave well.

screenshot here: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/510bvcp4tc9j442/Screenshot_2014-06-15-13-16-08.png)

This is my laucher activity:

```
public class ProjectActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private boolean hasTwoPanes;
private String TAG = "ProjectActivity";
private int parent_id = 0;
private long filter_id = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.acitivity_projects_list);
    getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.projects);

    if(savedInstanceState == null)
        newFragment(parent_id);
    else {
        parent_id = savedInstanceState.getInt("parent_id");
        filter_id = savedInstanceState.getLong("filter_id");
    }
}


public void newFragment(int parent_id){

    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    state.putInt("parent_id", parent_id);
    ProjectsListFragment list_fragment = new ProjectsListFragment();
    this.parent_id = parent_id;
    list_fragment.parent_id = parent_id;
    list_fragment.setArguments(state);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    transaction.replace(R.id.list, list_fragment, "" + parent_id);
    transaction.addToBackStack("" + parent_id);
    transaction.commit();
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("parent_id", parent_id);
    outState.putLong("filter_id", filter_id);
}

@Override  
public void onBackPressed() {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();

    if(manager.getBackStackEntryCount() < 2){
        finish();
        return;
    }
    manager.popBackStackImmediate();
}



@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    setFilter(filter_id, (ProjectsListFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag(manager.getBackStackEntryAt(manager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName()));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(ProjectActivity.this).close();
}


protected void setFilter(long id, ProjectsListFragment list_fragment) {

    SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(ProjectActivity.this);
    ((ProjectsListAdapter)list_fragment.getListAdapter()).changeCursor(DatabaseManager.getProjectsCursor(mDatabase, list_fragment.parent_id, (int)id));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.project_action_bar, menu);

    menu.findItem(R.id.new_project).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            startActivity(new Intent(ProjectActivity.this, NewProjectActivity.class));
            return false;
        }
    });

    menu.findItem(R.id.new_sub_unit).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1)
                startActivity(new Intent(ProjectActivity.this, NewProjectActivity.class));
            else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProjectActivity.this, NewSubunitActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("parent_id", parent_id);
                startActivityForResult(intent, NewSubunitActivity.ADD_SUB_UNITS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_projects).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ProjectActivity.this, ProjectActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
            return false;
        }
    });

    menu.findItem(R.id.menu_filter).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(ProjectActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.simple_list_dialog, null);
            final ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            final SimpleDialogListAdapter adapter = new SimpleDialogListAdapter(ProjectActivity.this, DatabaseManager.getStatusCursor(DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(ProjectActivity.this)), SimpleDialogListAdapter.STATUS_FILTER);

            View header = LayoutInflater.from(ProjectActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.filter_row, null);
            ((TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.name_edit_txt)).setText("Default");
            ((TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.color_btn)).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            list.addHeaderView(header);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProjectActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle(R.string.filter);
            builder.setView(view);
            final AlertDialog filter_dialog = builder.create();

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int position, long id) {
                    position--;

                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    ProjectsListFragment list_fragment = (ProjectsListFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag(manager.getBackStackEntryAt(manager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName());

                    if(position >= 0) {
                        setFilter(filter_id = id, list_fragment);
                    }
                    else {
                        setFilter(filter_id = -1, list_fragment);
                    }

                    ((ProjectsListAdapter)list_fragment.getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    filter_dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            filter_dialog.show();

            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

}

```
public class ProjectsListFragment extends ListFragment {

private String TAG = "ProjectsListFragment";
public View header;
public int parent_id = 0;

public ProjectsListFragment() {     
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    if(getArguments() != null)
        parent_id = getArguments().getInt("parent_id");

    header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.project_list_header, null);
    ((TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.header_txt)).setText(DatabaseManager.getProjectPath(DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(getActivity()), parent_id));
    setListAdapter(null);
    getListView().addHeaderView(header);

    setListAdapter(new ProjectsListAdapter(getActivity(), parent_id, 0));
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);

    if(position == 0)
        return;

    Bundle state = new Bundle();
    parent_id = ((Cursor)getListAdapter().getItem(position)).getInt(0);
    state.putInt("parent_id", parent_id);
    ((ProjectActivity)getActivity()).newFragment(parent_id);
}
```

}

```
public class ProjectsListAdapter extends CursorAdapter{

private Activity mActivity;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private String TAG = "ProjectsListAdapter";
private SimpleDateFormat simple_format;

public ProjectsListAdapter(Activity mContext, int parent_id, int flags) {
    super(mContext, DatabaseManager.getProjectsCursor(DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(mContext), parent_id, 0), flags);
    this.mActivity = mContext;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.simple_format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
}

@Override
public void bindView(final View row, final Context mContext, final Cursor mCursor){

    TextView main_txt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.main_txt);
    TextView mod_txt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sub_txt);
    //TextView sub_txt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sub_txt);
    Button status_btn = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.status_btn);
    ImageButton options_btn = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.options_btn);

    final int index = mCursor.getInt(0);

    options_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            row.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_grey));
            rotate(0, 180, v);

            Point point = new Point();
            mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);

            Dialog dialog = Dialogs.getProjectSpinnerDialog(mContext, index, point.x);
            dialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    rotate(180, 360, v);
                    changeCursor(DatabaseManager.getProjectsCursor(DatabaseHelper.getDatabase(mContext), mCursor.getInt(1), 0));
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    row.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    main_txt.setText(mCursor.getString(2));

    mod_txt.setText(simple_format.format(new Date(mCursor.getLong(8))).toString());
    //sub_txt.setText(mCursor.getFloat(3) + "%");
    status_btn.setText(mCursor.getString(5));

    int color = mCursor.getInt(7);

    if(color == 0)
        color = -1;

    int gradient_start = Color.argb(133, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    int gradient_end = Color.argb(230, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BL_TR, new int[] {gradient_start, gradient_end});
    gd.setCornerRadius(0f);
    row.setBackground(gd);

}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position - 1);
}


@Override
public View newView(Context mContext, Cursor mCursor, ViewGroup mGroup) {
    View row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.projects_row, null);
    bindView(row, mContext, mCursor);
    return row;
}

public static void rotate(float from_degree, float to_degree, View view) {
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(from_degree, to_degree,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotateAnim.setDuration(500);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(rotateAnim);
}
```

}

```
06-15 22:02:55.242: D/skia(25588): ---- fAsset->read(1) returned 0
06-15 22:02:55.242: D/skia(25588): ---- fAsset->read(30) returned 0
06-15 22:02:55.242: D/skia(25588): ---- fAsset->read(4) returned 0
06-15 22:02:55.242: D/skia(25588): ---- fAsset->read(3) returned 0
06-15 22:02:55.242: D/skia(25588): ---- fAsset->read(4) returned 0
06-15 22:02:55.242: D/skia(25588): ---- fAsset->read(6) returned 0
06-15 22:02:55.242: D/skia(25588): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588): Failure retrieving icon 0x7f02000a in package com.holubowski.projectmanager
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.putCachedIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:904)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:661)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:151)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadDefaultIcon(ComponentInfo.java:167)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:156)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getActivityIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:681)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>(ActionBarView.java:252)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:593)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3298)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3358)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:314)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1920)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at com.holubowski.activitys.ProjectActivity.onCreate(ProjectActivity.java:47)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5185)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2154)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:146)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4949)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1043)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
06-15 22:02:55.242: W/PackageManager(25588):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 22:02:55.304: D/AbsListView(25588): Get MotionRecognitionManager
06-15 22:02:55.500: D/libEGL(25588): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_MRVL.so
06-15 22:02:55.507: D/libEGL(25588): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_MRVL.so
06-15 22:02:55.523: D/libEGL(25588): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_MRVL.so
06-15 22:02:55.539: D/GC(25588): <tid=25588> OES20 ===> GC Version   : GC Ver-988-JB-R4-RC2-GC20 
06-15 22:02:55.562: D/OpenGLRenderer(25588): Enabling debug mode 0
06-15 22:02:55.671: D/dalvikvm(25588): GC_CONCURRENT freed 222K, 14% free 7585K/8775K, paused 12ms+2ms, total 50ms
```

Found reason and fixed it!

For anyone who have similar problem, in my case the problem makes a lauch icon, I dont know why, but its seems to been corrupted and makes nullpointer exception when app starts, and then touchwiz on normal (not debugg mode) started freaking out.
To fix it just deleted this png and puts new.

Comment: Can you post your LogCat output?

Comment: Do you mean the launcher of Touchwiz?

Answer (score 0):

Add the launcher icon (png, 32bit) with appropriate size in each of the following folders:
- mdpi: 48x48
- hdpi: 72x72
- xhdpi: 96x96
- xxhdpi: 144x144
- xxxhdpi: 192x192
This stops Samsung's touchwiz home crashing